# Netty OIO Server Blocking tasks

Tags: netty

I am writing a Netty OIO Server with netty 4.0. It is actually a proxy server. So my handler goes to the origin server to process the request. I would like to know if I can have blocking tasks in an OIO Server.

Comment: You only get a advantage of netty's threading model if you using async tasks, netty is bad when calling blocking operations

Comment: Thanks. I have another question regarding OIO Server.                                   I run my server. Then I run my test with 1000 concurrent threads, it executes in 1342ms. I stop my server and test.                             Again immediately if I run the server and then the same test, my latency is 3359ms. But if I wait after the first test and then run the server and the test, my latency is again around 1300ms.   Can you guess why ?

Comment: netty needs some time to start the threads at the moment the first connection is made. after at least *cpucores* \* 2 different connections are made, all the worker threads are started, and the delay is gone.

Comment: Is there a way to create the worker threads beforehand ?